# HTML Animated Sequences WITHOUT canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I'm currently planning a web project that has a few animated sequences that need to run on the site.
I need the site to be as cross browser compatible as possible (duh!) and wanted to get fellow developers thoughts on different options.

Canvas is not an option mainly because of IE. IE9+ only support isn't good enough, even though the 'progression' of browser stats for IE is near on laughable
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp (13% for IE in March 2013 (AND IT COMES AS DEFAULT WITH ALL WINDOWS MACHINES) going slightly off topic...

I was planning on preloading a series of animated gifs for different stages of animations for example 'run', 'walk', 'fly' and then swap the src of an img tag as and when required. I haven't tested anything like this yet, but i invisage delays even with preloaded images (though javascript http://www.preloadjs.com )
although im not too keen on the quality of animated GIFS. taking this idea a little further, using the same method but with each from as a seperate PNG? is that feasible?

Or could a DOM element with a spritesheet attached as the background image work, changing the background position on each step?

Any thoughts or examples ;) would be very helpful! :)

Cheers,
Rory!

---EDIT

im also open to different javascript libraries.. although currently included in my project are [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and [Rapheal](http://www.raphaeljs.com)

Comment: Maybe you can use animating SVG (with IE fallback, that I can't find right now)? I'm not sure how the IE fallback will handle animation though. Normal SVG will animate fine (using jQuery eg).

Comment: Currently i am using RafaelJS which using SVG and then falls back on some sort of sorcery to make IE6 work. but I wasn't aware that you could do bitmap sequecne animations with it, i'll do some digging, thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm very curious what you find. Keep us uptodate?

Comment: Bank holiday weekend! When i get in the office tomorrow and experiment i will keep you updated with my findings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is going to be your best bet.  Buf you have time to generate a sprite sheet to show different animation stages, then you may have enough time to look into a good jquery plugin like [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/), which allows you animate sprite sheet items.

Comment: Thank you, even though i dont think using gameQuery would be useful for me as im not building a game and there is a lot of overhead with unneeded stuff. But seeing that example was usfull as i can see they have gone about doing the animation. sprite sheet and moving the background position! thanks, ill have do a quick browserstack.com test to check its cross browser compatibilty

Comment: @RoryPickering you are absolutely right in your observation.  You really don't need to build a "game" with the plug-in.  As long as you know what your target goals are and have some trained experience with javascript, you can use gameQuery for anything that requires javascript animations.  It doesn't have to be a game.  Plus its a real flexible package that works on mobile and desktop devices. Good luck!

Comment: thanks dude! just did a quick test on ie6-7-8-9 on broswer stack and it doesn't show the animated charaters on 6 & 7. Which to be fair is still better than canvas. so it's definilty an option for when i start this project!